# asp.net sessions not stored in sql

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I have coded my own `custom session state provider` based on `entity framework` using asp.net mvc 5 website template project with individual user accounts.
When I start my application, register a new website user and login, no session information such as `UserId` is stored in the database tables unless I manually set some values to `Session` variable. After debugging my `custom session state provider` I can say that it works well, but it is not what I wanted.

I suppose that every website page load starts the new session with a unique session id or continues the current one, session id is stored in browser cookies and is written to the database via `custom session state provider`. I try to achive such application behavior, how can I implement such application behavior?

After a 6 mounth of struggling on this problem I got totally

**UPDATE**

I wanted to track all sessions in the database even empty sessions for anonymouse users but the new sessions database records are created only if I set some values to `Session` variable. I also need to force logout user from all computers/browsers on password change. It is something complex with asp.net session state mechanism I can't understand.

```
public class WebsiteSessionStateProvider : SessionStateStoreProviderBase
{
    WebsiteDbContext m_DbContext;
    int m_Timeout;

    public WebsiteDbContext DatabaseContext
    {
        get
        {
            return m_DbContext ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<WebsiteDbContext>();
        }
        private set
        {
            m_DbContext = value;
        }
    }

    public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
    {
        if (config == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(config));
        base.Initialize(name, config);

        var applicationName = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath;
        var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(applicationName);

        var configSection = (SessionStateSection)configuration.GetSection("system.web/sessionState");
        m_Timeout = (int)configSection.Timeout.TotalMinutes;
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public override SessionStateStoreData GetItem(HttpContext context, string id, out bool locked, out TimeSpan lockAge, out object lockId, out SessionStateActions actions)
    {
        return GetSessionItem(context, id, false, out locked, out lockAge, out lockId, out actions);
    }

    public override SessionStateStoreData GetItemExclusive(HttpContext context, string id, out bool locked, out TimeSpan lockAge, out object lockId, out SessionStateActions actions)
    {
        return GetSessionItem(context, id, true, out locked, out lockAge, out lockId, out actions);
    }

    private SessionStateStoreData GetSessionItem(HttpContext context, string id, bool exclusive, out bool locked, out TimeSpan lockAge, out object lockId, out SessionStateActions actions)
    {
        locked = false;
        lockAge = new TimeSpan();
        lockId = null;
        actions = 0;

        var SessionItem = DatabaseContext.Sessions.Find(id);

        if (SessionItem == null) return null;

        if (SessionItem.IsLocked)
        {
            locked = true;
            lockAge = DateTime.UtcNow - SessionItem.TimeLocked;
            lockId = SessionItem.LockId;
            return null;
        }

        if (DateTime.UtcNow > SessionItem.TimeExpires)
        {
            DatabaseContext.Entry(SessionItem).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
            return null;
        }

        if (exclusive)
        {
            SessionItem.LockId += 1;
            SessionItem.IsLocked = true;
            SessionItem.TimeLocked = DateTime.UtcNow;
            DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        locked = exclusive;
        lockAge = DateTime.UtcNow - SessionItem.TimeLocked;
        lockId = SessionItem.LockId;

        var data = (SessionItem.Content == null)
            ? CreateNewStoreData(context, m_Timeout)
            : Deserialize(context, SessionItem.Content, m_Timeout);

        data.Items["UserId"] = SessionItem.User.Id;

        return data;
    }

    public override void ReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext context, string id, object lockId)
    {
        var SessionItem = DatabaseContext.Sessions.Find(id);
        if (SessionItem.LockId != (int)lockId) return;

        SessionItem.IsLocked = false;
        SessionItem.TimeExpires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(m_Timeout);
        DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public override void SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext context,
                                                    string id,
                                                    SessionStateStoreData item,
                                                    object lockId,
                                                    bool newItem)
    {
        var intLockId = lockId == null ? 0 : (int)lockId;
        var userId = (string)item.Items["UserId"];

        var data = ((SessionStateItemCollection)item.Items);
        data.Remove("UserId");

        var Content = Serialize(data);

        if (newItem)
        {
            var session = new Session
            {
                SessionId = id,
                User = DatabaseContext.Users.Find(userId),
                TimeCreated = DateTime.UtcNow,
                TimeExpires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(m_Timeout),
                TimeLocked = DateTime.UtcNow,
                IsLocked = false,
                Content = Content,
                LockId = 0,
            };

            DatabaseContext.Sessions.Add(session);
            DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
            return;
        }

        var state = DatabaseContext.Sessions.Find(id);
        if (state.LockId == (int)lockId)
        {
            state.User = DatabaseContext.Users.Find(userId);
            state.Content = Content;
            state.TimeExpires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(m_Timeout);
            state.IsLocked = false;
            DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public override void RemoveItem(HttpContext context, string id, object lockId, SessionStateStoreData item)
    {
        var state = DatabaseContext.Sessions.Find(id);
        if (state.LockId != (int)lockId) return;

        DatabaseContext.Entry(state).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public override void ResetItemTimeout(HttpContext context, string id)
    {
        var SessionItem = DatabaseContext.Sessions.Find(id);
        if (SessionItem == null) return;

        SessionItem.TimeExpires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(m_Timeout);
        DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public override SessionStateStoreData CreateNewStoreData(HttpContext context, int timeout)
    {
        var data = new SessionStateStoreData(new SessionStateItemCollection(),
                                                SessionStateUtility.GetSessionStaticObjects(context),
                                                timeout);

        data.Items["UserId"] = String.Empty;
        return data;
    }

    public override void CreateUninitializedItem(HttpContext context, string id, int timeout)
    {
        var session = new Session
        {
            SessionId = id,
            User = null,
            TimeCreated = DateTime.UtcNow,
            TimeExpires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(timeout),
            TimeLocked = DateTime.UtcNow,
            IsLocked = false,
            Content = null,
            LockId = 0,
        };

        DatabaseContext.Sessions.Add(session);
        DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public override bool SetItemExpireCallback(SessionStateItemExpireCallback expireCallback) { return false; }
    public override void EndRequest(HttpContext context) { }
    public override void InitializeRequest(HttpContext context) { }

    private byte[] Serialize(SessionStateItemCollection items)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new BinaryWriter(ms);

        if (items != null) items.Serialize(writer);
        writer.Close();

        return ms.ToArray();
    }

    private SessionStateStoreData Deserialize(HttpContext context, Byte[] serializedItems, int timeout)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream(serializedItems);

        var SessionItems = new SessionStateItemCollection();

        if (ms.Length > 0)
        {
            var reader = new BinaryReader(ms);
            SessionItems = SessionStateItemCollection.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        return new SessionStateStoreData(SessionItems, SessionStateUtility.GetSessionStaticObjects(context), timeout);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should improve your question by adding some code samples that explain your problem a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> no session information such as UserId is stored in the database tables unless I manually set some values to Session variable

That's exactly what a session provider is for: abstract the storage of session data from the web application.

If you don't put anything in the session, your provider won't store anything.